# How to get all references to a node using the TypeScript API?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Use case: given a variable declaration like `let i = 0` or `const j = getSomething();`, figure out if the variable is an int, float, or anything else (not just `number` vs non-`number`). To do this, I'm assuming the general way to do that is to find all places the value is set, figure out their types (recursively), and see if any set it to something other than an int.

I have access to a `ts.TypeChecker` and `ts.Program` if need be. A couple of [tweets from Daniel Rosenwasser](https://twitter.com/drosenwasser/status/959975228548956160) indicate the checker API is the way to go, but I can't figure out which APIs to use.

[Relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/general-language-syntax/TS-GLS/issues/4) & [relevant source file](https://github.com/general-language-syntax/TS-GLS/blob/38f0b41679fe8a0d3e7ed19b62c91300bbd0583a/src/nodes/visitors/variableDeclarationVisitor.ts).

Edit: This isn't as simple as `typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation`. Suppose we have the following block:

```
function someScope() {
    let myInt = 0;
    let myFloat = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
        myInt = i;
        myFloat = i;
    }

    if (external) {
        myInt = 7;
    } else {
        myFloat = 7.5;
    }

    return myInt * myFloat;
}
```

I'm trying to get a program crawling the tree to understand that `myInt` is really an `int` (not just a general `number`), while `myFloat` is of type `float` and `someScope` returns `float` (not `int`).

The "worst case" scenario would be to crawl through the variable's containing scope, find all references to it, and recursively get their types. Surely there must be a standard way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean `let i:any = remoteServer.getSomethingUnexpected()` ? Because otherwise you  should already know the type.

Comment: @Kokodoko this is with the TypeScript API for static analysis - not development time type checking.

Comment: For now, I'm using tsutils' `collectVariableUsage`. It only works for uses within the file, though.

Comment: https://github.com/ajafff/tsutils/blob/ded73655ea3fb1603bc3cdf8056a8a07961dd3cf/util/usage.ts#L158

Answer (score 1):

You can do like:

```
const ts = require('typescript');
const service = ts.createLanguageService(host);
let identNode;
function visit(node) {} // ...visit and find decl of your ident blahblah
for (const file of service.getProgram().getSourceFiles()) {
    if (!file.isDeclarationFile) {
        ts.forEachChild(file, visit);
    }
}
const refs = service.findReferences(identNode.getSourceFile().fileName, identNode.getStart());
const refNodes = new Set();
refs?.forEach(ref => {
   const { references } = ref;
   references?.forEach(reference => {
       const sourceNode = service.getProgram().getSourceFile(reference.fileName);
       ts.forEachChild(sourceNode, node => {
           // traverse stuff..., logic as:
           // if node.textSpan === references.textSpan
           // refNodes.add(node);
       });
   })
})
```

"refNodes" are what you need. And you can also see similar code at [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/build/lib/mangle/index.ts#L410)